# Android FragmentActivity how to pass variables to Fragments?

Tags: android, sliding, android-fragmentactivity, fragmentpageradapter

I have a perfectly fine running FragmentActivity with a smooth horizontal sliding between the (identical) Fragments. I was wondering now how I can send a variable to the Fragment objects?

My code looks like this:

```
    private void initialisePaging() {

    fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();

    for (int i = 0; i < wiList.length; i++) {
        WhiteboardImage tmpWi = wiList[i];

        intent.putExtra("displayNow", tmpWi.getFilename());
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, GalleryFragment.class.getName()));
    }

    this.mPagerAdapter = new GalleryPagerAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);

    ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) super.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    pager.setAdapter(this.mPagerAdapter);

    // Define which item of the list will be displayed
    pager.setCurrentItem(4);
}
```

So basically in the for() loop I am adding multiple times the GalleryFragment object to the PagerAdapter. What I now want to do is that each GalleryFragment gets a different ID (or string for that matter). I could not figure out how to pass a different value to each GalleryFragment object within that loop. At the moment each object gets the very same value.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually made it like this:
If the data are available from beginning and not change then I parsed them as parameters of fragment.instantiate. then in this function you can put them as a Bundle with .putArguments(...) to your fragment. And in your fragment's onCreate you can retrieve the data with .getArguments(...)

Comment: Thanks. I just figured that out at the same time but have a different problem now. I am using this code:

Comment: sorry my previous comment was being blocked while I was still editing it. I meant to say:
Fantastic! It works wonderfully like that! :-]

Comment: Any idea how to access variables if they are *not* available from the beginning?